# ggplot lines for shapes, change the length not the overall size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to compare some data and I have 4 variables.

What I'm looking for is a way to plot the "tumour_depth" represented by the length of a line at each (platform, SV_count) location on the axes.

```
  platform SV_count tumour_depth    patient
1 Nanopore       30     34.00000 17
2 Nanopore        4     23.00000 95
3 Illumina       88     72.90999 97
4 Nanopore       38     26.00000 20
5 Illumina       39     83.93676 82
```

My plotting code:

```
A %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=platform, y=SV_count, size=tumour_depth, group = patient)) +
    geom_point(shape="-", width=0.01) +
    scale_radius(range=c(0,50)) +
    theme_light()
```

However, using my approach above, the lines get both thicker and longer when I use them.   Also, the legend gets really large.   is there a better way to use lines as the marker shapes in my plot where I can control just the length of the line and not the overall size?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a `geom_segment`. However, overall I would suggest to map `tumor_depth` on `x` and facet by `platform`. Doing so you don't need a legend and IMHO comparing the lengths is much easier.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(A, aes(x = tumour_depth, y = SV_count, group = patient)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = 0, yend = SV_count), linewidth = 4) +
  facet_wrap(~platform) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
A <- structure(list(
  platform = c(
    "Nanopore", "Nanopore", "Illumina",
    "Nanopore", "Illumina"
  ), SV_count = c(30L, 4L, 88L, 38L, 39L),
  tumour_depth = c(34, 23, 72.90999, 26, 83.93676), patient = c(
    17L,
    95L, 97L, 20L, 82L
  )
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1",
  "2", "3", "4", "5"
))
```